# Como executar um socket php

Tags: php, linux, socket, websocket, php-cli

Esse script a baixo se trata de um socket php para receber dados de um rastreador veicular tk102.
O problema é que eu acho que ele tem que ser executado em uma pasta especifica no servidor e não sei como se faz isso, e tem essa questão do script de CLI que não sei oque é. Se alguém ja trabalhou com algo parecido e poder me ajudar eu agradeço

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php

/* Listens for requests and forks on each connection*/
$ip = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx';
$port = 3007;
$__server_listening = true;
error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_time_limit(0);
ob_implicit_flush();
declare(ticks = 1);
if(!isset($argv[1]) || $argv[1] != '-f') {
become_daemon();
}
/* nobody/nogroup, change to your host's uid/gid of the non-priv user */
change_identity(65534, 65534);
/* handle signals */
pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, 'sig_handler');
pcntl_signal(SIGINT, 'sig_handler');
pcntl_signal(SIGCHLD, 'sig_handler');
/* change this to your own host / port */
server_loop($ip, $port);
/**
* Change the identity to a non-priv user
*/
function change_identity( $uid, $gid )
{
if( !posix_setgid( $gid ) )
{
    print "Unable to setgid to " . $gid . "!\n";
    exit;
}
if( !posix_setuid( $uid ) )
{
    print "Unable to setuid to " . $uid . "!\n";
    exit;
}
}
/**
* Creates a server socket and listens for incoming client connections
* @param string $address The address to listen on
* @param int $port The port to listen on
*/
function server_loop($address, $port)
{
GLOBAL $__server_listening;
if(($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
{
    echo "failed to create socket: ".socket_strerror($sock)."\n";
    exit();
}
if(($ret = socket_bind($sock, $address, $port)) < 0)
{
    echo "failed to bind socket: ".socket_strerror($ret)."\n";
    exit();
}
if( ( $ret = socket_listen( $sock, 0 ) ) < 0 )
{
    echo "failed to listen to socket: ".socket_strerror($ret)."\n";
    exit();
}
socket_set_nonblock($sock);

echo "waiting for clients to connect\n";
while ($__server_listening)
{
    $connection = @socket_accept($sock);
    if ($connection === false)
    {
        usleep(100);
    }elseif ($connection > 0)
    {
        handle_client($sock, $connection);
    }else
    {
        echo "error: ".socket_strerror($connection);
        die;
    }
}
}
/**
* Signal handler
*/
function sig_handler($sig)
{
switch($sig)
{
    case SIGTERM:
    case SIGINT:
        exit();
    break;
    case SIGCHLD:
        pcntl_waitpid(-1, $status);
    break;
 }
 }
 /**
 * Handle a new client connection
 */
 function handle_client($ssock, $csock)
{
GLOBAL $__server_listening;
$pid = pcntl_fork();
if ($pid == -1)
{
    /* fork failed */
    echo "fork failure!\n";
    die;
}elseif ($pid == 0)
{
    /* child process */
    $__server_listening = false;
    socket_close($ssock);
    interact($csock);
    socket_close($csock);
}else
{
    socket_close($csock);
}
}
function interact($socket)
{
    /* TALK TO YOUR CLIENT */
$rec = "";
socket_recv($socket, $rec, 2048, 0);
$parts = split(',',$rec);
$cnx = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mpitech', 'mpi0147#');
/*
Array
(
    [0] => 0908242216
    [1] => 0033663282263
    [2] => GPRMC
    [3] => 212442.000
    [4] => A
    [5] => 4849.0475
    [6] => N
    [7] => 00219.4763
    [8] => E
    [9] => 2.29
    [10] =>
    [11] => 220809
    [12] =>
    [13] =>
    [14] => A*70
    [15] => L
    [16] => imei:359587017313647
    [17] => 101Q
    [18] =>
)
*/
$trackerdate            = mysql_real_escape_string($parts[0]);
$phone              = mysql_real_escape_string($parts[1]);
$gprmc              = mysql_real_escape_string($parts[2]);
$satelliteDerivedTime       = mysql_real_escape_string($parts[3]);
$satelliteFixStatus         = mysql_real_escape_string($parts[4]);
$latitudeDecimalDegrees     = mysql_real_escape_string($parts[5]);
$latitudeHemisphere         = mysql_real_escape_string($parts[6]);
$longitudeDecimalDegrees    = mysql_real_escape_string($parts[7]);
$longitudeHemisphere        = mysql_real_escape_string($parts[8]);
$speed              = mysql_real_escape_string($parts[9]);
$bearing            = mysql_real_escape_string($parts[10]);
$utcDate            = mysql_real_escape_string($parts[11]);
// = $parts[12];
// = $parts[13];
$checksum           = mysql_real_escape_string($parts[14]);
$gpsSignalIndicator         = mysql_real_escape_string($parts[15]);
if(ereg("imei",$parts[16]))
{
    $imei               = mysql_real_escape_string($parts[16]);
    $other              = mysql_real_escape_string($parts[17].'       
'.$parts[18]);
}
else
{
    $imei               = mysql_real_escape_string($parts[17]);
    $other              = mysql_real_escape_string($parts[18].'        
'.$parts[19]);
}


$today = date("Y_m_d");
               $file = fopen("log/LogPagSeguro.$today.txt", "ab");
               $hour = date("H:i:s T");
               fwrite($file,"Log de Notificações e consulta\\\\r\\\\n");
               fwrite($file,"Hora da consulta: $hour \\\\r\\\\n");
               fwrite($file,"HTTP: ".$http['http_code']." \\\\r\\\\n");
               fwrite($file,"Código de Notificação:".$notificationCode."     
  \\\\r\\\\n");
               fwrite($file, "Código da transação:".$email."\\\\r\\\\n");
               fwrite($file, "Status da transação:".$status."\\\\r\\\\n");



  fwrite($file,"________________________________________________ \\\\r\\\\n");
               fclose($file);





$imei = substr($imei,5);
//mysql_select_db('mpi2015_rio2016_triplem', $cnx);
//if($gpsSignalIndicator != 'L')
//  mysql_query("INSERT INTO gprmc (date, imei, phone, trackerdate, satelliteDerivedTime, satelliteFixStatus, latitudeDecimalDegrees, latitudeHemisphere, longitudeDecimalDegrees, longitudeHemisphere, speed, Bearing, utcDate, Checksum, gpsSignalIndicator, other) VALUES (now(), '$imei', '$phone', '$trackerdate', '$satelliteDerivedTime', '$satelliteFixStatus', '$latitudeDecimalDegrees', '$latitudeHemisphere', '$longitudeDecimalDegrees', '$longitudeHemisphere', '$speed', '$bearing', '$utcDate', '$checksum', '$gpsSignalIndicator', '$other')", $cnx);
//mysql_close($cnx);
}
/**
* Become a daemon by forking and closing the parent
*/
function become_daemon()
{
$pid = pcntl_fork();

if ($pid == -1)
{
    /* fork failed */
    echo "fork failure!\n";
    exit();
}elseif ($pid)
{
    /* close the parent */
    exit();
}else
{
    /* child becomes our daemon */
    posix_setsid();
    chdir('/');
    umask(0);
    return posix_getpid();
}
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CLI significa Command Line Interface.

Para executar um script PHP escrito para CLI, basta acessar o terminal (console, ssh, cmd, shell console, etc).

Pelo shell do Linux, execute o comando:

```
>/usr/bin/php /local/do/script.php
```

Isso é o suficiente para executar.

Note também que nesse trecho há um parâmetro opcional

```
if(!isset($argv[1]) || $argv[1] != '-f') {
become_daemon();
}
```

Para usá-lo, execute assim

```
>/usr/bin/php /local/do/script.php -f
```

obs: Não precisa digitar `>` no início dos comandos. O sinal `>` é apenas para representar o ambiente de um shell. (aquela telinha preta).

Certifique-se também do local correto do binário PHP. Nos exemplos acima coloquei como `/usr/bin/php` mas pode estar em outro local no seu servidor.

Comment: Esse PHP dentro de bin   é uma pasta?

Comment: é o compilador do php... um arquivo binário...